# Reading a file with a batch with n tokens including empty ones

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, token

I want to write a batch script which reads each line of a file. Sounds easy but the problem is that not every line has the same amount of tokens. The next thing is that every token is seperated from each other with a delimiter which I don't want to have in my output.

Here is a example of the file:

```
string1|string2|string3|string4
string1|||string4
```

When I'm reading that file, every token has to be on its right place. What I mean is when I'm reading the second line the output must be:

> string1 empty empty string4

thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

But I found out that I had another problem. The count of the tokens are not always the same and the count is often about 20-40 tokens at one line. 
I created a solution with a sub-procedure:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (Book1.csv) DO (
set "work=%%a"
for /l %%i in (1,1,2) do set "work=!work:||=|NULL|!"
set "line=!work!"
call :processToken
)
goto eof


:processToken
for /F "tokens=1* delims=|" %%x in ("!line!") do (
echo %%x
set line=%%y
)
if not "!line!" == "" goto :processToken
goto :eof
:eof
```

Answer (score 0):

[gawk](/questions/tagged/gawk) for Windows can do the job:

```
awk -F"|" "{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) $i=$i?$i:\"empty\"};7" file.in>file.out
```

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
(
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (q21551753.txt) DO (
 SET line=%%a
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 SET line=!line:^|= ^|!
 ECHO(!line!
 endlocal
)
)>tempfile.txt
SET "spaces=                                                     "
FOR /f "tokens=1-7delims=|" %%a IN (tempfile.txt) DO (
 SET "$a=%%a%spaces%"
 SET "$b=%%b%spaces%"
 SET "$c=%%c%spaces%"
 SET "$d=%%d%spaces%"
 SET "$e=%%e%spaces%"
 SET "$f=%%f%spaces%"
 SET "$g=%%g%spaces%"
 SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
 ECHO(!$a:~0,8!!$b:~0,9!!$c:~0,8!!$d:~0,8!!$e:~0,9!!$f:~0,5!!$g:~0,6!
 endlocal
)

GOTO :EOF
```

I used a file named `q21551753.txt` for my testing.

```
string1|string2|string3|string4
string1|||string4
|string2||string4|string5|string6
%one%|!2!||"three"|^four^|string6
```

Response:

```
string1 string2  string3 string4                     
string1                  string4                     
        string2          string4 string5  strin      
%one%   !2!              "three" ^four^   strin
```

Note that the column-widths are defined in the `ECHO(!$a...` statement - your choice of the number and width of each column. Note that `spaces` is set to a bunch of spaces.

`tempfile.txt` is created. Whether you delete this, where it is created and what you call it are all up to you.

Answer (score 0):

The following assumes data does not contain `!`, and no line begins with `;`. These restrictions can be eliminated with more code.

The key trick is to use variable expansion search and replace to convert `str1|str2|str3|str4` into `"str1"|"str2"|"str3"|"str4"`. Then a second FOR /F can safely parse the tokens, even when the value is missing. The values you want are in `%%~A`, `%%~B`, `%%~C`, and `%%~D`. The line I ECHO is just to demonstrate the values of each token.

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%L in (test.txt) do (
  set "ln=%%L"
  set "ln="!ln:^|="|"!""
  for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=|" %%A in ("!ln!") do (
    echo A=%%~A B=%%~B C=%%~C D=%%~D
  )
)
```